# How to get the <b> tag value in this html with Selenium Webdriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium

How can the Webdriver xpath function be used to get the  tag value in the snippets below? The Java code is not working as expected.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p class="fontlarg">
    QC_NUM：<b>8300</b>
    </code>
</p>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
String valueOfbTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/p[1]/b[1]")).getText();
```

Comment: what's the string you are getting in the code written in question? Can you try with this? "//p[1]/b[1]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is an absolute xpath `/p[1]/b[1]` is expecting the root element in your xhtml to be `p` where I expect that you have `html` as your root element.

To solve this you can make it relative `//p[1]/b[1]` this will find all `p` elements in your tree and then find the first `b` element inside the first `p` element.

Te make this more specific you can select only the `p` elements with the correct class `//p[@class='fontlarg'][1]/b[1]`.

Comment: tks ,yes i want to get this element value on<pre>html</pre>,this is website:[link](http://www.weidea.net/blog/category/%E8%B4%AD%E7%89%A9%E5%95%86%E5%9F%8E/opencart%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98/), in this page i want to get b tag value,using this java code:    <pre>WebElement a2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/ul/li/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/b[1]")); System.out.println(a2.getText())</pre>,but  still can't get  the value.

Comment: try `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='fontlarg'][1]/b[1]"))` and debug the element.